# NoLoggingT does not disable logging in Persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, haskell-persistent

I've made this piece of code and I'm puzzled with two things:

- why do the two pieces work differently, one logging and another not?
- why does the second piece log if there is a NoLoggingT wrapper added on the `selectFoobars`?

Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Logger.CallStack
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ReaderT)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (ResourceT)
import Data.String.Class (toString)
import Database.Esqueleto
import Database.Persist.Sqlite (createSqlitePool)
import qualified Database.Persist.Sqlite as P
import Database.Persist.TH
import GHC.Natural
import System.Log.FastLogger (fromLogStr)

instance MonadLogger IO where
  monadLoggerLog _loc _src _lvl msg =
    putStrLn (toString (fromLogStr (toLogStr msg)))

share
  [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
  [persistLowerCase|
Foo
  bar Natural
|]

runSomeQuery :: ConnectionPool -> Natural -> IO (Maybe Natural)
runSomeQuery pool aid = do
  flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    _ <- selectFooBars aid
    return Nothing

selectFooBars ::
     Natural -> ReaderT SqlBackend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) [Entity Foo]
selectFooBars aid = do
  logDebugN "This should not log?"
  select . from $ \s -> do
    where_ $ (s ^. FooBar ==. val aid)
    limit 1
    return s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  logDebugN "MAIN"
  P.runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
    logDebugN "STARTING UP 01"
    runMigration migrateAll
    _ <- selectFooBars 123
    return ()
  budgetPool <- createSqlitePool ":memory:" 1
  logDebugN ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
  logDebugN ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
  logDebugN ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
  logDebugN "STARTING UP 02"
  _ <- runSomeQuery budgetPool 975
  return ()
```

Fully buildable repo can be found at https://github.com/k-bx/nologesqueleto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the logging function is assigned to the connection information itself, and `createSqlPool` assigns wherever you run your `createSqlitePool` in:

```
createSqlPool
    :: (MonadLogger m, MonadUnliftIO m, IsSqlBackend backend)
    => (LogFunc -> IO backend)
    -> Int
    -> m (Pool backend)
createSqlPool mkConn size = do
    logFunc <- askLogFunc
    liftIO $ createPool (mkConn logFunc) close' 1 20 size
```

And `runSqlite` explicitly runs its code in a `NoLoggingT`:

```
runSqlite :: (MonadUnliftIO m, IsSqlBackend backend)
          => Text -- ^ connection string
          -> ReaderT backend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a -- ^ database action
          -> m a
runSqlite connstr = runResourceT
                  . runNoLoggingT
                  . withSqliteConn connstr
                  . runSqlConn
```

So if you change the code to:

```
  budgetPool <- runNoLoggingT $ createSqlitePool ":memory:" 1
```

it will stop logging. It still doesn't respect the `NoLoggingT` in the `selectFooBars` type annotation, which is slightly confusing.